# Authorization_Code SignOutAsyn() not trigger endsession

Tags: identityserver4

I have a portal secured by Identity Server with Authorization_code grant type
the

```
HttpContext.SignInAsync(ClaimsPrincipal)
```

works fine and redirect the user with claims to the portal however the

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

method is not working where it is not triggering the endsession endpoint to redirect the user to the logout action under identity server

```
public async Task Logout()
{            
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync
                    (CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

}

startup.cs
ConfigureService(IServiceCollection services)
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie(cookieOptions =>
            {
                var tempProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                cookieOptions.Cookie.Name = "PortalAuth";
                cookieOptions.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;

                cookieOptions.SessionStore = 
                 tempProvider.GetRequiredService<ITicketStore>();
                configureCookieOptions?.Invoke(cookieOptions);
            })
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(                    
               IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                idServOptions =>
                {
                    idServOptions.Authority = 
                       options.AuthorizationServiceUrl;
                    idServOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    idServOptions.ApiName = options.ApplicationName;
                    idServOptions.ApiSecret = options.ApplicationSecret;
                    idServOptions.EnableCaching = true;
                    idServOptions.CacheDuration = 
                           TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                    idServOptions.SupportedTokens = 
                                SupportedTokens.Reference;
                   configureIdentityServerOptions?.Invoke(idServOptions);
                    idServOptions.Validate();
                });

var client = new Client{
...
 RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:12345" },
 PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:12345" },
}
```

What else I am missing in the setup to trigger the endsession endpoint.
If I need to call endsession manually then how to get the id_token_hint and I am using authorization_code grant type

```
var disco = await 
            DiscoveryClient.GetAsync(Constants.AuthorizationServiceUrl);
            var endSessionUrl = new 
             RequestUrl(disco.EndSessionEndpoint)
            .CreateEndSessionUrl(IdTokenHint:?,State:?);
            return Redirect(endSessionUrl);
```

Comment: Any help would be appreciated